# Why is the browser changing my single quotes to double and ruining my JSON in the data attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

This should be way easier than it is, but it's got me stuck.

Im putting some JSON in an input data attribute and the quotes on the first key are closing the attribute.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var html = `<input type="checkbox" data-values='${dataVals}' />`;
```

Where dataVals is a JSON string like this

```
'{"checked":true,"unchecked":false}'
```

But it's showing up in the browser like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-values="{"checked":true,"unchecked":false}">
```

And the browser is reading it essentially as though it's this.

```
data-values="{"
```

Which obviously isn't what I want.

I'm clearly missing something. Any thoughts?

Comment: `data-` attributes probably aren't the best approach. What are you actually attempting to achieve?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: If you want to set a data attribute, I'd suggest using `jQuery.data()`.

Comment: *"But it's showing up in the browser like this"* That's just how the DOM view shows it, not how it was actually delivered. If you want to know how it's actually delivered, use the "view source" option which shows you your own raw HTML. *"And the browser is reading it essentially as though it's this"* No, it isn't: https://jsfiddle.net/ucb87xaf/

Comment: How are you trying to read that `data-values` element?  If you are using jQuery, then `$element.data('values')` should give you an object.  Is it just giving you the string `'{'`?

Comment: @BoltClock it's not shown in the question, but eventually it gets injected into the html with jquery.

Comment: @itcropper: How are you doing that "injection"?  Maybe that's where the issue lies?

Comment: @RocketHazmat when I do something like JSON.parse($('element').data('values')) it give me an error, probably because "{" isn't valud JSON.

Comment: @RocketHazmat $.append()

Comment: @itcropper: Can you show that `$.append()` code?  That's probably where your issue is.  Or rather, maybe it's just how you're building the `html` value shown, maybe it's being (or not being) escaped properly.  Does `console.log(html)` show you the correct value with the correct quotes?

Comment: Added HTML seems even worse: `data-values="{&quot;checked&quot;:true,&quot;unchecked&quot;:false}"` ...

Comment: @Teemu: That's perfectly valid (er, it would be without the hidden characters). Remember, attribute text is HTML text. `&quot;` is `"`.

Comment: Copied from the console (Chrome), but I can't see any hidden characters ..?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue here is, but if you use `JSON.stringify` before appending to the `data-values` parameter then everything works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/asy0zyj3/

Comment: @ShreyanshGandhi the `data()` function of jQuery only reads the `data-*` attribute, it neither sets the data attribute nor the dataset property. If you set data using `data()` it will store this data in an internal jQuery storage.

Comment: @t.niese: Yes, but you can also use `.data()` to *set* data values for an element.  jQuery stores them... somewhere, but they can be read back again with `.data()`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, yes you can set data for an element, but cannot set a _data attribute_ with `data()`.

Comment: @t.niese: Fair enough :)

Comment: @Teemu: *"...but I can't see any hidden characters..?"* LOL - That's because they're hidden! There's a U+200C and U+200B before the final `:` in that comment. I've seen those inserted by JSBin, possibly others. No idea why. gvim shows me hidden characters which has been handy more than once.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, it sounds funny = ). But after your "er" comment, I did paste my clipboard content to jsFiddle, and didn't see any hidden characters. That has to be something in SO comments only, since now when I copied the code from the comment, a couple of hidden characters indeed occurs at jsFiddle as well.

Comment: @Teemu: Doh! And I even knew that happens: [Stop inserting invisible characters into comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295425/stop-inserting-invisible-characters-into-comments)

Answer (score 1):

Combination of @T.J. Crowder and @Teemu

I added a replace at the end of the json string to replace double quotes with `&quot;`

```
JSON.stringify({ ... }).replace(/\"/g, "&quot;")
```

Then also stopped trying to run JSON.parse() when I wanted to get the value later since $.data('values') already returns a javascript object (when it can).

```
JSON.parse($(this).data('values')) => $(this).data('values')
```